# How to put div element between the two elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom

I run wordpress website and I want to add the following elements between specific elements using JavaScript.

```
<div id="wrap" style="display:none;border:1px solid;width:500px;height:300px;margin:5px 0;position:relative"></div>
```

However, no matter how many hours I look at numerous examples on the internet and follow along, the div element is not added...

Website structure is

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
   <p class="billing_postcode_find_field">..
       <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">...
       </span>
     </p>
   <div id="wrap" ..> </div> <- want to put div here

   <p class="billing_address_1_field">
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
```

And

i tried below codes.

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("warp");
  document.billing_address_1_field.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
}

or

<script>
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "wrap");
    let par = document.getElementsByClassName("billing_postcode_find_field")[0];
    par.appendChild(newDiv);
</script>
```

Could someone please let me know what am I missing?

Website link is [here][1]

Thank you.
[1]: https://seoartgallery.com/test5/?page_id=15/?add-to-cart=34&quantity%5B1%5D

Comment: For one ..  `InsertBefore` is being used incorrectly, as there is no variable `billing_address_1_field`  ..   Second you have misspelled `wrap / warp` in the HTML / JS.  There is a lot wrong with your code.

Comment: Are you trying to add something to the checkout?

Comment: Hi, @HowardE  Yes. When a customer clicks on the "Find Postal Code" button on the checkout page,

I would like to implement an address search bar to appear below the button.

Currently, the address search window appears as a pop-up, but there is a blocking problem on mobile.

The address search bar is a common method in S.Korea, but I'm having a hard time adding it under checkout field in Woocommerce.

Comment: Look at jQuery `ajaxcomplete` https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to add this new element as the first child of the `.woocommerce-input-wrapper` element. In this case, you can use `prepend()`

```html
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <p class="billing_postcode_find_field">
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
            <p class="billing_address_1_field">
                <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">this is the span in p tag</span>
            </p>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
    const parent = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-input-wrapper');

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrap');
    newDiv.innerText = `I'm new!`;

    parent.prepend(newDiv);
</script>
```

If there were to be an element above the `.billing_address_1_field` element, then you could use `.insertBefore()` instead to ensure that it would go in between the elements you want it to:

```html
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <p class="billing_postcode_find_field">
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
            <p>i'm a random p tag at the top of the container</p>
            <p class="billing_address_1_field">
                <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">this is the span in p tag</span>
            </p>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
    const parent = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper');
    const billingField1 = document.querySelector('.billing_address_1_field');

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrap');
    newDiv.innerText = `I'm new!`;

    parent.insertBefore(newDiv, billingField1);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, @mstephen19. Thanks for answering.  I've tested both types of code and it still doesn't work.

It throws an error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore') .

I've tried changing the Class and ID of parent and child several times, but it still doesn't work. 

I don't know why it's not working on my website.

The element structure of the WooCommerce checkout page confuses me even more.

Is there any other way I can try? Thank you.

Comment: Finally!! solved. i just moved code below </body>.  I really appreciate you. Thank you!